# In eclipse, when i import something it import that with full package name instead of importing that at top of file?

Tags: java, spring

If I import Autowired then it is importing with full package every time.

```java
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
private com.productcrud.service.ProductService productService;
```

Similar things happen with other classes as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is related to [Spring](https://spring.io/) but rather to your [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) preferences.

I believe you need to set this:

[image: Eclipse preferences]

You open the *Preferences* window from the *Eclipse* menu.

[image: Eclipse menu]

Comment: Hey Abra  it works Thanks !! This is happening from past 2 months . U really saved my life.